# Finding Thevenin Eq Resistor

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have tried to solve this problem for a very long time and keep getting the wrong answer but am absolutely baffled at this point what I have wrong.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fobahq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My equations are as follows.

vcvs1 = (I2-I1)(-j300)

Loop1: 9+600-j300)I1+j300I2 = 0

Loop2: 2(I2-I1)(-j300)+(-j300)I2+300I2-300I3+j300I1 = 0

Loop3: -1+300I3 - 300I2 = 0

Then (-1)/I3 = Rth

The answer should be 247angle(-16 degree)

But this does not work out to that at all it's something around 90.

Am I just getting something simple wrong?

Comment: vcvs is dependent on what?

Comment: If you can clarify on what voltage and by what factor does the VSCS depend on, i can help

Comment: I think it's dependent on the voltage across C1. But this is only IMO.

Comment: are you sure about the solution 247 <16`  ?? i get the solution as 240 + 120i when i take VCVS as  2 times volatge across Vc ,please clarify the vcvs dependency

Comment: Isn't it: 600 // -j300 // 300 ?

Comment: Yes the VCVS is controlled by the voltage across C1.

Comment: I guess I  can't be positive I know the answer but that is the answer that we were given in class.  Either way I don't get anything close to either answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this.  The problem is that I was forgetting to remove all independent sources when adding in the new source.  By removing the old independent sources and using only the 1V source I get the correct answer.

Rth: 147.2 angle 16degree

Vth: 3.7 angle -15.9degree